# How do I run android tests in the emulator using IntelliJ?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-emulator, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run the sample unit tests for the sample code that ships with the android SDK. Some of the tests run as standard unit tests, no problem. Other tests, such as com.example.android.apis.view.Focus2AndroidTest, use android classes, and therefore need to run in the emulator, that is a problem.

I can run applications just fine in my emulator. When I run tests, though, my emulator starts up, and then just sits there. The test never runs. All I see in the output window in IntelliJ is

```
Waiting for device.
/Users/rfzabick/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/emulator -avd MyAvd0 -netspeed full -netdelay none
Device connected: emulator-5554
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
After @CrazyCoder's advice, I switched to android 4.0.3 (API 15). Here's what I got:
Testing started at 4:34 PM ...

```
Waiting for device.
/Users/rfzabick/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/emulator -avd android4.0.3--api15 -netspeed full -netdelay none -wipe-data -no-boot-anim
Device connected: emulator-5554
Device is online: emulator-5554
Target device: emulator-5554 (android4.0.3--api15)
Uploading file
    local path: /Users/rfzabick/IdeaProjects/ApiDemos/out/production/Tests/Tests.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis.tests
Installing com.example.android.apis.tests
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis.tests"
Device is not ready. Waiting for 20 sec.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis.tests"
Device is not ready. Waiting for 20 sec.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis.tests"
Device disconnected: emulator-5554
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis.tests


Running tests
Test running startedTest running failed: com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
Empty test suite.
```

The only relevant thing I see in logcat is

```
01-21 16:36:22.047: WARN/ActivityManager(91): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis.tests
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you run normal apps in the emulator or USB device? Try to create the new emulator device and see if helps.

I've tried it with IDEA 11.0.1, 4.0.3 Android platform on Windows and it works fine:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: emulator-5554 (ICS)
Uploading file
    local path: D:\dev\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-15\ApiDemos\out\production\Tests\Tests.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis.tests
Installing com.example.android.apis.tests
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis.tests"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis.tests
Success


Running tests
Test running startedFinish
```

You can also try to restart adb with `adb kill-server` and start the emulator manually from AVD manager.

Verify that there is no pre-installed ApiDemos application in the emulator, or the signatures will not match. Uninstall existing ApiDemos, then try to deploy and run ApiDemos from IntelliJ IDEA, then try to run the test configuration again.

---

**UPDATE:** We did some research and found the source of the problem. By default IntelliJ IDEA sets the dependency scope for the application module inside test module to **Compile**, so that all the production and test classes get compiled into the single Test.apk.

Instead, the scope must be set to **Provided** and we'll fix it in the next update. Right now you need to correct it manually as shown on the screenshot:

[image: Provided scope]

Rebuild the project and run the tests, again, this time 2 separate apk files will be deployed, one for the main app and the second one for the tests, then tests will run:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: emulator-5554 (ICS)
Uploading file
    local path: D:\dev\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-15\ApiDemos\out\production\Tests\Tests.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis.tests
Installing com.example.android.apis.tests
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis.tests"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis.tests
Success


Uploading file
    local path: D:\dev\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-15\ApiDemos\out\production\ApiDemos\ApiDemos.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis
Installing com.example.android.apis
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.apis
Success


Running tests
Test running startedFinish
```

Comment: I can run apps in the emulator with no problem. It's unit tests that I can't run.

Comment: Any related errors in logcat panel? Did you try with the new emulator instance and re-installed ApiDemos application? Did you try with 4.0.3 (15) platform?

Comment: I've tried that, and added the results above. No luck. Any other things to try?

Comment: Try to wipe the SDK and install it from scratch.

Comment: Please check the updated answer with the fix to dependency scope.

Comment: ApiDemos is a large sample, target apk is about 3MB, your machine may be not fast enough to handle it. Try with some smaller sample project. Another option is to run it again without closing the emulator to ensure that OS is fully loaded and is not lagging when the apk is installed. Or you can try running the emulator manually from the AVD Manager, wait a couple of minutes and then run the tests.

Comment: Thanks. I needed that, plus I had to fix a misconfiguration in my run configuration. In my android test configuration, I specified module Snake instead of module Tests. I hadn't paid attention to that drop down, but since I was testing the Snake module, seeing it in the dropdown didn't seem out of place. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the instrumentation from ant, from the command line of from a script. In case you prefer the latter this [post](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/04/running-instrumentation-from.html) may be of help.

Answer (score -1):

Running unit tests in emulator is not practical (basically takes too long).  And since android jars are usefull only to compiling, it seems impossiblble to run them with unit tests.  Good alternative is use of advanced mocking framework ( I personally prefer jMockit, 
but there are other )

See example:

https://github.com/ko5tik/andject/blob/master/src/test/java/de/pribluda/android/andject/ViewInjectionTest.java

Here I test my class against derived android activity, and it has to call superclass methods
(this runs in maven, eclipse or IDEA on the spot )

Comment: I know that I *could* mock things out in my own tests. But the sample apps that ship with the android SDK come with unit tests that need to run in an emulator. Surely it is possible to run these tests.

Comment: On a decent x86 machine with x86 binaraies fo ryour AVD, HAXM installed (Mac) and GPU enabled the emulator can be faster than a real device - and makes testing on many different API levels easy and self-contained in your "PC". Don't limit yourself to testing on real devices - Bad Advice.

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda  What do you mean it takes too long?  I have a Linux machine, and the latest Android emulators are very fast on it.