# emulator Device is not ready waiting for 20 sec

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am using **intelliJ IDEA12.1.3** for **Android** Development.

I am running hello world app but when emulator is launched there comes message in commandline that device is not ready wait for 20 sec.

```
Uploading file
local path: C:\Users\Haseeb\IdeaProjects\untitled\out\production\untitled\untitled.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.untitled
Installing com.example.untitled
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.untitled"
Device is not ready. Waiting for 20 sec.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.untitled"
Device is not ready. Waiting for 20 sec.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.untitled"
Device is not ready. Waiting for 20 sec.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.untitled"
Device is not ready. Waiting for 20 sec.
```

Comment: Do you see the emulator in `adb devices` command output in `online` state?

Comment: Check this link. it worked for me.

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936363/how-do-i-run-android-tests-in-the-emulator-using-intellij

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If anything goes wrong starting the emulator, you can get the Device not ready message "forever".   Even if things go perfectly it can take five minutes or so to start sometimes -- especially after you wipe user data.  Kill the run or debug attempt (look for a red square) and start the emulator from the AVD manager, then wait for it to get to the home screen before trying to run or debug your app.

I usually begin my work day with Android by starting the emulator from the AVD Manager (sometimes I start more than one if I'm testing different devices/android versions, etc) then leaving them up all day long. Unless your program does something really awful, running another debug session will kill the old copy and install and run a new one so there's no reason to start and stop the emulator.

Comment: PS: Snapshots can help the startup time dramatically.